# Hide/show div content by class

Tags: javascript

I have this code which works to hide/show div content by id. I need to change it to identify content by div class. How can I do that?

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))">Click here</a>
```

Javascript

```
function hideshow(which){
                if (!document.getElementById)
                    return
                if (which.style.display=="block")
                    which.style.display="none"
                else
                    which.style.display="block"
            }
```

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery? This is super-simple in jQuery, but of a pain in vanilla js.

Comment: You can't google on how to get the element by class?

Comment: Yes, i'm able to use jQuery @BFDatabaseAdmin

Comment: @nicael i can google it yes, i did for last 2 hours. I don't have enough knowledge of javascript. I couldn't figure it out how to resolve this situation, that's why I ask here :)

Comment: @62009030 - very simple jQuery solution posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just making it work with most selectors

```
function hideshow(which){

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(which);

    [].slice.call(elems).forEach(function(el) {
        if ( el.style.display === 'none' ) {
            el.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}

hideshow('.elements');
```

or with jQuery

```
$('.elements').toggle()
```

Comment: I really need to check it by class. Or it it possible to check just by first part of the id?

Comment: Using a period (`.`) selects by class, using a hash (`#`) selects by ID, this does get elements by class, or any other selector for that matter

Comment: got this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector."

Comment: Now you're passing an element to the function, not a selector

Comment: shouldn't be like this:<a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('.adiv'))">Click here</a>

Comment: No, it shouldn't be like that, you can't use `getElementById` to get elements by class, it should be obvious from the name

Comment: just one simple thing. What I have to change to first HIDE and just after click it shows? :) @adeneo

Comment: Then you just hide the elements with CSS to start with

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="hideshow('adiv')" >Click here</a>
```

---

```
function hideshow(which){
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName(which),
        el_node = els[0];
    if (el_node.style.display === "block"){
        el_node.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el_node.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5L8d7ukf/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

**HTML**

```
<a class="toggleVisibility">Click here</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggleVisibility", function() {
    $('.which').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {display:none;}
```

Or you could flip it using `.show` and `display:block` if you wanted to start with the items hidden.

Comment: Thanks ! @BFDatabaseAdmin. I could resolve my problem